# Where is the ActiveSync / MS Exchange Source within the Android OS Code-Base

Tags: android, email, exchange-server, activesync

Ever since Froyo (Android 2.2), Google's Android OS has supported syncing Microsoft Exchange accounts using the ActiveSync protocol.  I am trying to find Android's implementation of the ActiveSync protocol within the Android code-base.

Does anyone know where ActiveSync is implemented in Android? I have been rummaging around the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/android) but cannot find it.

Comment: I suspect that it is not released, as I suspect that Microsoft's licensing would preclude an open source implementation. That's just a guess, though.

Comment: I don't think so, Z-push (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-push) is a free and open-source implementation of ActiveSync. I can't find Android's though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Right here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Exchange/+/master/src/com/android/exchange), enjoy.

[EDIT] - if there are issues accessing the link above, the source is also on [omapzoom.org](http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Exchange.git). To see individual code files there, navigate to a "tree" link for any of the commits and dig down into the `src` folders. Here's [an example](http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Exchange.git;a=tree;f=src/com/android/exchange;h=b509488e9786d47bdc258bca6e69a73c369b6fc8;hb=10ff736cbd2a7546bfc5c97cd85d034d9e2f85fa).

Comment: Chrome warns this link contains malware.

Comment: Alternative link added.

Comment: speedplane..were you able to download and build the client? I haven't been able to do build the source

Comment: Did this link get hijacked? It seems to point to a spammer site now.

Answer (score 1):

Just download from the android git repository. If you are on linux, then `wget -r --no-parent https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Exchange/+/master/exchange2/src/com/android/exchange` ought to do it.